# TeamCity - exclude Entity Framework classes from .NET project test coverage

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, test-coverage

I am using TeamCity as CI tool. I want to exclude all the Entity Framework generated models. I've been trying different syntax and options for a while and nothing seems to do the trick.

I read the documentation, read all the question on the topic I could find, but still nothing seems to work for me.

I have a *Repository* project within my *App* solution. It has two classes - *RepositoryOne.cs* and *RepositoryTwo.cs.*

I have a lot of classes within edmx file from EF. I don't want to included them in the code coverage.

I tried having something that will only include files that contain Repository, but without success. I haven't tried to exclude single files, because they are more than a hundred.

something like

```
+:App.Repository.RepositoryOne
+:App.Repository.RepositoryTwo
-:App.Repository.*
```

I know this will not work, but just trying to explain better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dotCover, then there are two solutions.

**First:**

Move all your edmx classes to separate project and remove it from coverage on a assembly filters:

```
-:App.Repository
```

**Second:**

Use Attribute filters to remove whole namespace from coverage:

```
-:App.Repository.RepositoryOne
```

Here is a screenshots how this could look like in TeamCity with assembly and attribute filters - just pick one option:

[image: TeamCity assemmbly and attribute filters]

More about dotCover:  https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/JetBrains+dotCover

More examples: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/12/10/coverage-with-dotcover-teamcity-mstest-nunit-or-mspec/

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't get it working in an opposite fashion for the Attribute filters though:
      -:App.Repository
      +App.Repository.RepositoryOne

The idea is that I want to skip all the files but two. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Imho it's not possible to exclude all classes in a file. Either whole namespace, or picking classes one by one. If I were you, I would create custom namespace for all EntityFramework classes like `App.Repository.EF` and exclude them with attribute filters.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `dotCover` you can specify an xml file to describe the class or modules you want to analyse, or ignore:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AnalyseParams>
 <TargetExecutable>c:\nunit\nunit-console.exe</TargetExecutable>
 <TargetArguments>C:\Sources\out\Debug\MyLib.dll</TargetArguments>
 <TargetWorkingDir>C:\Sources\out\Debug\</TargetWorkingDir>
 <Output>coverage.xml</Output>
 <Filters>
   <IncludeFilters>
     <FilterEntry>
        <!-- We just want to cover repository classes -->
        <ClassMask>*Repository*</ClassMask>
     </FilterEntry>
   </IncludeFilters>
   <ExcludeFilters>
     <FilterEntry>
        <!-- Do not cover Test projects -->
        <ModuleMask>*Test</ModuleMask>
     </FilterEntry>
   </ExcludeFilter>
 </Filters>
</AnalyseParams>
```

This is a sample, feel free to match your needs.

Using a configuration file, you will be able to get the code coverage in local if you have dotCover easily, and you will not depend of Teamcity to run it.

For more informations about the configuration file, you can have a look on Console Runner Commands, inside dotCover [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html). Or, run:

`dotcover cover` without parameters, to get the help on the command line, and get a sample of a configuration file.